# All Browsers automatically go "back" in history

Tags: windows, browser

I am suffering from a strange behaviour of Windows XP on my HP Pavilion DV2000 laptop: when I open any browser (Firefox, Chrome, IE, ...) it always automatically goes back to the previous page, until it reaches the very first opened page.

I checked possible causes:

1. Backspace key is stuck? No, it was not!
2. Virus or malware: I used many antivirus or malware removers but no virus or malware was detected. Reinstalling Windows did not fix the problem.

What could I do now? Is it a hardware bug?

Answer (score 0):

I had this very same problem just a moment ago. I thought "what is going on"?! No keys stuck,  I could type as usual. Every single browser acted odd .. hammering the back button all the time.

Turns out, my remote's back button was jammed and causing this.